# Is there a way to "extract" Windows 10 apps from one computer and install them in another computer offline without Windows store?

Tags: windows-10

I need to install several apps from one computer to other. I tried to use this utility but it simply crash and didn't work:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Back-Up-and-Recovery/Windows-8-Apps-Data-Backup.shtml

Or is there a way to download an App from Windows store and install it in many computers offline?

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 can be used on its own to just run software without installing at all.

Use cameyo system snapshots to compile into a singe `*.exe` file which can be changed into a `*.appx` file with Windows 10 SDK Tools.

## Step 1: Compile

The process of turning a software into a virtual package is called "packaging". The process consists of installing a software while Cameyo "captures" it. Once this is done, you will be able to use this software on any machine without having to re-install it again. Also, virtual software can work in "isolated
mode", never interfering with your Windows stability (unlike regular software).

*Note: packaging should be done on a clean virtual machine as otherwise, snapshotting will take a **very** long time. Avoid packaging on any machine which has other software & components installed on it.*

1. Launch Cameyo's Packager:
   Launch Cameyo and select "Capture an installation" in the startup menu.
2. Wait for the Packager to capture a pre-installation snapshot of your system in its current state.
3. Once the snapshot is taken, A window will appear asking you to install.
   At this point, install the appx you wish to package, and if needed, configure your application the way you want it to run.
4. When your appx file finishes installing, press "Install done" on Cameyo's packager window.
   Cameyo will again take a few minutes to establish a snapshot of your system (this time post-installation) and analyze the differences.
5. You're done! The package is placed under the "My documents\Cameyo packages" folder:

## Step 2: Convert

*Note: to sign the app, you will need Windows 10 SDK Tools and a Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise Edition 64-Bit running Creators Update.*

1. Download and install the [Desktop App Converter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/desktopappconverter/9nblggh4skzw) from Windows Store.
2. Download both the `DesktopAppConverter.zip` and `BaseImage-14316.wim` files.
3. Extract the downloaded `DesktopAppConverter.zip` file to a folder on your computer and
4. Place the `BaseImage` file in the same directory.

*If there’s a new build of Windows 10 available, you should see a new `BaseImage` file. You’ll need to use the `BaseImage` file with the same version number as your installed build of Windows 10.*

Next, open a PowerShell window as Administrator. To do so, open the Start Menu, search for “PowerShell”, right-click its shortcut, and select “Run as Administrator.”

Change PowerShell’s execution policy by running the following command. Agree to the change by typing `y` afterwards.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
```

You can now run the `DesktopAppConverter.exe` command from an Administrator PowerShell window to convert a desktop application to a UWP application in a single command. You’ll need the application’s `*.cameyo.exe` file to do this.

Here’s a command you can use and adjust for your application:

```
.\DesktopAppConverter.exe -AppExecutable C:\Installer\MyApp.exe  -Destination C:\Output\MyApp -PackageName "Name" -Publisher "CN=Publisher" -Version 0.0.0.1 -MakeAppx -Verbose
```

You’ll need to adjust the command to add your own publisher name, version, package name, and point it at the installer file and destination directory you prefer.

## Step 3: Signing

If you have administrative privileges on the computer of installation, do the following command in Powershell Administrator.

```
Add-AppxPackage -Path C:\Path\to\AppxManifest.xml -Register
```

You’ll find the `AppxManifest.xml` file next to the `Application.appx` file in the output directory you specified.

If you don't have admin on the recipient computers, take the long route as follows:

**REMEMBER, W10 PRO/ENTERPRISE IS REQUIRED**

Open PowerShell as an admin on the computer where you just created the *.appx file.
Do the following command: `cmd`, then do:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64"
MakeCert.exe -r -h 0 -n "CN=Publisher" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -pe -sv my.pvk my.cer
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk my.pvk -spc my.cer -pfx my.pfx
signtool.exe sign -f my.pfx -fd SHA256 -v C:\Path\to\application.appx
```

Note that the Publisher name is the same name as when you created the `*.appx` file in the `MakeCert.exe` command.

You’ll be asked to enter a password. You can just leave the password blank.

Now, you have a `*.appx` file ready for installation on other computers! **Enjoy!**

---

If for some reason the computer is acting up, Do 
`Add-AppxPackage C:\Path\to\application.appx` in PowerShell (No Admin Required)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation of how to use the product to solve the problem.

Comment: Please follow [these rules](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690) while recommending software.

Comment: Updated after Creators update rolled out to Australia

Answer (score 1):

There is no "official" way to do so as users in Windows. [You can do it if you are Administrator and need to deploy apps to various machines](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/distribute-offline-apps), however not all apps are deployable like this.

Another "not official" way to do so is by "intercepting" the installation packages needed for an app to work, refer to this tutorial for more info:
It worked in Windows 8/8.1, I am not using Windows anymore, so I have not checked in Windows 10, but should work, just make sure you get the appx files for the app and related dependencies.
[Download windows appxs offline.](http://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/)

Comment: While the information in this answer might be correct it does not specifically explain how to accomplish the user's goal within the answer itself.